# R: get the unique values of categorical data sorted by another categorical variable

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a data like the following and I want to know the percentage of people who have bought from more than 2 brands:

```
     hh_code    brand
     3032145       536
     3032145       53
     3032145       534
     324063        536
     204128        53
     84787         536
```

and I want to the number of brands bought by each household - like the following:

```
   hh_code    unique_ brand
   3032145    3
   847827     1
   204128     1
    84787     1
```

I have tried using table but it is just giving me frequencies. 
Would appreciate any insights!

Comment: This is a pretty common question. You could also use `table(df$hh_code)` which would work for your example or if HHs buy the same brand multiple times, `table(unique(df)$hh_code)` should work for a data.frame with 2 columns.

Comment: ok, thanks! I tried table(df$hh_code, df$brand) before and it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .(unique_brand = uniqueN(brand)), by = hh_code]
#   hh_code unique_brand
#1: 3032145            3
#2:  324063            1
#3:  204128            1
#4:   84787            1
```

Comment: That was an impressively quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, base R solution using `tapply`:

```
num_brands <- tapply(df$brand, df$hh_code, length)
ge2_brands <- num_brands > 2
```